# delete row by id

Tags: oracle, position, row

I'm in the middle of creating a tool similar to the SQL Developer table data viewer. My db is Oracle based.

I simply need to delete eg.: 'row number 3' from a SELECT result. That table doesn't have any PK nor unique records. I've tried various techniques with ROWNUM etc. but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a [`ROWID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/pseudocolumns008.htm) pseudocolumn that you can use for this purpose *in simple cases*.

```
select rowid, ... from your_table where ... ;
delete from your_table where rowid = <what you got above>;
```

If your interface allows the user to make complex views/joins/aggregates, then knowing what the user intended to delete (so knowing what set of `rowids` to gather and what set of tables to delete from) is going to be tricky.

Warning: `rowids` are unique only within a given table, and, quoting the above documentation:

> If you delete a row, then Oracle may reassign its rowid to a new row inserted later.

So be very, very careful if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is a standard heap-organized table (index-organized tables and clusters potentially introduce additional complexity), if you don't have any other way to identify a row, you can use the `ROWID` pseudocolumn.  This gives you information about the physical location of a row on disk.  This means that the `ROWID` for a particular row can change over time and the `ROWID` can and will be reused when you delete a row and then a subsequent `INSERT` operation inserts a new row that happens to be in the same physical location on disk.  For most applications, it is reasonable to assume that the `ROWID` will remain constant between the time that you execute the query and the time that you issue the `DELETE` but you shouldn't try to store the `ROWID` for any period of time.

For example, if we create a simple two-column table and a few rows

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 number, col2 varchar2(10) );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 1, 'Justin' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 1, 'Justin' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 2, 'Bob' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 2, 'Charlie' );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

We can `SELECT` the `ROWID` and then `DELETE` the third row using the `ROWID`

```
SQL> select *
  2    from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1 Justin
         1 Justin
         2 Bob
         2 Charlie

SQL> select rowid, col1, col2
  2    from foo;

ROWID                    COL1 COL2
------------------ ---------- ----------
AAAfKXAAEAABt7vAAA          1 Justin
AAAfKXAAEAABt7vAAB          1 Justin
AAAfKXAAEAABt7vAAC          2 Bob
AAAfKXAAEAABt7vAAD          2 Charlie

SQL> delete from foo where rowid = 'AAAfKXAAEAABt7vAAC';

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1 Justin
         1 Justin
         2 Charlie
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ROWID instead of ROWNUM.

Comment: Thanks... I kinda missed that.